# Having trouble with an exercises which asks me to check a value

Tags: java

I am working through the exercises in Objects First With Java (for review before test). One exercises asked me to create a checkIndex method, which I have done correctly. The next part asks me to rewrite both my listFile and removeFile methods so that they use my checkIndex method to make sure a valid parameter has been input. I am not sure how to do this and have tried a few things. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class MusicOrganizer
{
// An ArrayList for storing the file names of music files.
private ArrayList<String> files;

/**
 * Create a MusicOrganizer
 */
public MusicOrganizer()
{
    files = new ArrayList<String>();
}

/**
 * Add a file to the collection.
 * @param filename The file to be added.
 */
public void addFile(String filename)
{
    files.add(filename);
}

/**
 * Return the number of files in the collection.
 * @return The number of files in the collection.
 */
public int getNumberOfFiles()
{
    return files.size();
}

/**
 * List a file from the collection.
 * @param index The index of the file to be listed.
 */
public void listFile(int index)
{
        String filename = files.get(index);      //not sure
        System.out.println(filename);
    }




/**
 * Remove a file from the collection.
 * @param index The index of the file to be removed.
 */
public void removeFile(int index)
{
    if(index >= 0 && index < files.size()-1) {
        files.remove(index);
    }
}

public String getfive(){
    return files.get(4);
}

public void addNew(String whatIsYourFavourite){
    files.add(whatIsYourFavourite);
}

public void remove(){
    files.remove(2);
}

public void checkIndex(int check){
    if ((check >= 0) && (check <= files.size()-1)){

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Valid range must be between 0 and -1");
    }

}

public boolean checkIndex2(int check2){
    if ((check2 >= 0) && (check2 <= files.size()-1)){
       return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: why so complicated? check2 <= files.size()-1
this does the same: check2 < files.size()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually this should be relatively easy. Assuming your code is correct for both remove and check index you can thereby use checkindex2 to return a boolean in the if statement. So you have

```
    public void removeFile(int index)
    {
        if(checkindex2(index))
 {
            files.remove(index);
        }
    }
```

and for the list

```
    public void listFile(int index)
        {
               if(checkindex2(index)){
                System.out.println(files.get(index));
            }
}
```